# Windows 7 Activation key stop working

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation, product-key

I tried to upgrade to Windows 10 a few days ago. Something went wrong, and my computer began to operate extremely slow.  After several unsuccessful attempts at troubleshooting, I decided to reinstall Windows. Before doing so, I used RecoverKeys  to obtain my Product Key, so that I can activate after reinstallation. However, I am now getting an error that says, "The  product key you typed has been blocked by use by Microsoft."

This is strange, considering I never had this problem in the past; I have successfully reinstalled Windows a few times  before. I did a little research, and learned that a hardware change could possibly trigger this problem; I recently  upgraded my computer's RAM. I put the old RAM chips back in, but that didn't solve the problem. I also used DBAN to  completely wipe the drive before reinstalling, but that didn't work either. The weirdest thing is that the "Product ID" is  still the same as the ID listed in the RecoverKeys text file, except for the last two numbers.

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate, and my computer is a Samsung laptop model R-580.

Comment: Your key is on the COA

Answer (score 0):

This is not strange at all. The key is in use as part of the Windows 10 upgrade, which you deleted. Had you used the rollback function, the key would no longer be in use.

I have also contacted Microsoft support on this matter and they confirmed that an upgrade keeps the license/product key upon which it is based “in use”.

I read somewhere that Microsoft does currently not have a manual way to revert the license upgrade, but I’m unable to find the source.

Comment: Yes try do; you use phone activation; this is the silliest answer I have read in awhile

Comment: I’m currently searching for the source. It clearly stated there was no way for Microsoft to manually undo the license upgrade. That of course includes phone activation.

Comment: Hey everyone, I want to add some info which may be helpful.

I found a tool called "LegitCheck," and it says my Windows is genuine. I also saved the following to a text file (I forgot where I got the info):

Diagnostic Report (1.9.0019.0):
-----------------------------------------
WGA Data-->
Validation Status: Genuine
Validation Code: 0

Cached Validation Code: N/A, hr = 0xc004f012
Windows Product Key: *****-*****-T8Q9T-F28CM-JD6YQ

Those letters in the Product Key are the same as those that Windows was rejecting...

Comment: @Mayur If you want to add info, edit your question. ;) Unfortunately, I haven’t been able to find the news article where they talked about that, sorry. I believe it was German, though.

Comment: Just because an upgrade is done does not mean the license that was upgraded is lost

Comment: @Ramhound Of course it is “lost”. It is in use, because the Windows 7 license is part of the Windows 10 Upgrade license. This is the way upgrades work and why they’re cheaper than a full license.

Comment: Except there is not such thing as a Windows 10 upgrade license, when you upgrade, the same rights are transferred ( retail or OEM ) read the EULA...

Comment: But there is. Maybe not in a legal way, but it’s there. After an upgrade has been confirmed with license servers, the upgraded installation will have a generic product key, much like an OEM system. That means, however, that the Windows 7 key would not be in use. To work around this, it is blocked for use with Windows 7. That’s what you refer to as “transferred”.